# Copy UV Islands to another UV set?

Tags: uv

Can you copy UV islands from one set to another on the same mesh? I have two UVs that are mixed up and I want to separate them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe UVMagic addon already in Blender. You can copy from objects to other objects, faces etc. its simple to use, hope it helps!

Features

- 11:40 Copy/Paste UV (Among faces in UV/Image Editor)
- 0:07 Copy/Paste
  UV (Among objects)
- 0:51 Copy/Paste UV (Among faces in 3D View)
- 1:51 Transfer UV

Tutorial and feature list here

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKZX3Xac7X4